AVD Emulator Connecting forever spin Android Studio Hedgehog
I've installed Android Studio in order to learn Kotlin via Udemy. So I'm new at this.
After installing, I created a new AVD in Device Manager. Left the memory settings on default. Gave the AVD a name (Pixel_7_API34) with OS UpsideDownCake.
When I try to start the Virtual device, I get "Connecting to the Emulator" with the throbber that never ends.
My system specs/resources are: Win10Pro, Ryzen 7 3700X, 64gb mem, PCIe and SSD drives (plenty of drive space), X570 AORUS ULTRA mb.  RTX 3070 Ti GPU.  System built for video editing.
I've tried deleting and re-creating the AVD, rebooting, re-installing the Studio to no avail.
I've tried a few of the answers here but they are 10 years old and don't really apply to this version.
Anyone have suggestions?  TIA
UPDATE: I've managed to get it to work by creating a lower pixel AVD. I went with Pixel 6 and API 30. Worked. Then tried Pixel 7 API 34 again and it did not work (original problem). So I deleted it and its files (had to also end the emulator task in task manager) and created Pixel 7 API 33. Works! So the issue is using API 34 with Pixel 7. In my Udemy course we are instructed to create Pixel 7 API 34, which is why I did.
